# Set background of layout to part of the image

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that if I have a background image, no matter how big it is, and  I set the root layout ( say linearlayout) to have this image as background, then it is made to fit the screen.

Now my question, is there a way I can set the background of the layout to part of the image (so that if I pan using gesture, I can view the other parts of the background image)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why dont you divide your layout into two? Show/Hide one half on keypad pop?

Comment: It is not limited to two. I want to to set the background to part of the image depending on  where the user is ( think of it like strategy game or action game where you have a map and you are navigating)

Comment: You will have to draw each element of the background separate I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you have to make two image put it in framelayout use this code this color code match class   


public class ColorTool {
public boolean closeMatch (int color1, int color2, int tolerance) {
    if ((int) Math.abs (Color.red (color1) - Color.red (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
    if ((int) Math.abs (Color.green (color1) - Color.green (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
    if ((int) Math.abs (Color.blue (color1) - Color.blue (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;

    return true;
} // end match

}

get background color of background image by this method

public int getHotspotColor(int hotspotId, int x, int y) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(hotspotId);
        if (img == null) {
            Log.d("ImageAreasActivity", " Hot spot image not found");
            return 0;
        } else {
            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap hotspots = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());
            if (hotspots == null) {
                Log.d("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot bitmap was not created");
                return 0;
            } else {
                img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                return hotspots.getPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
set ontouchlistener on that image and implement ontouch method like this


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handledHere = false;
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
        final int evY = (int) ev.getY();
        int nextImage = -1;

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        if (imageView == null)
            return false;

        Integer tagNum = (Integer) imageView.getTag();
        int currentResource = (tagNum == null) ? R.drawable.backgroundimage
                : tagNum.intValue();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (currentResource == R.drawable.backgroundimage) {
                nextImage = R.drawable.setimage;
                handledHere = true;
            } else
                handledHere = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            int touchColor = getHotspotColor(R.id.image_areas, evX, evY);
            ColorTool ct = new ColorTool();
            int tolerance = 25;
            nextImage = R.drawable.backgroundimage;
               if (ct.closeMatch(Color.RED, touchColor, tolerance))
                nextImage = 0;
            else if (ct.closeMatch(Color.GREEN, touchColor, tolerance))
                nextImage = 1;
            else if (ct.closeMatch(Color.BLUE, touchColor, tolerance))
                nextImage = 2;
            else if (ct.closeMatch(Color.WHITE, touchColor, tolerance))
                nextImage = 3;
            if (currentResource == nextImage) {

                nextImage = -1;
            }
                        handledHere = true;
            break;

        default:
            handledHere = false;
        } // end switch

        if (handledHere) {

            if (nextImage == 0) {

                /* put your code of setbackground image here for first matching color code */
            }
            if (nextImage == 1) {
            /* put your code of setbackground image here for second matching color code */
                iv.setOnTouchListener(null);
            }
            if (nextImage == 2) {

                /* put your code of setbackground image here for third matching color code */
                iv.setOnTouchListener(null);
            }
            if (nextImage == 3) {

            }
        }
        return handledHere;
    }


layout 

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image_areas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/homeback2"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/homefront2"/>
           <!--  android:scaleType="centerCrop" -->
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a bit close to what I want . But not exactly. think of it like strategy game or action game where you have a map and you are moving around. So you are display new/different parts of the image. That's what I want. I want to set background to a specific area in the image depending on point of time. I will accept your answer being closest though unless you can provide better answer (then I will upvote it as well)

Answer (score 0):

put this line in xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/li"    
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      /* this line is for setting background image  */ 
      android:background="@drawable/Image"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and if you want to change image by code put this line

```
          linearlayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.li);
          linearlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

Comment: I am not asking about how to set background to an image. I am asking about how to set background to a portion of the image

Comment: you have to make two image put it in framelayout use this code